# Azure ad multi tenant api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a asp.net web api (A) which is azure ad protected multitenant api, it interns calls another api which is not multiTenant.

Now the client which is accessing my api is also a azure ad protected  multitenant application. Now when it is trying to acquire a token for the second tenant user it's failing saying that it dose not recognize the app.

Is it mandatory as a multitenant application to have all the dependent APIs also configured as Multi tenant?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scenario, but generally speaking, you'd expect multi-tenant APIs to call other multi-tenant APIs.

If an API is not multi-tenant, it's indicating that the scope of its data and functionality is limited to a specific tenant. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to call it requesting information from a user in tenant that the API doesn't support.

I can only think of one valid scenario for this setup: the multi-tenant API is also registered in the same directory as the non-multi-tenant API and accesses it via the app-only flow with the intent of accessing user-agnostic APIs.